# IOS Charts - Limit Line appears twice after refreshing data

Tags: ios-charts, swift3.2

I'm using iOS Charts by Daniel Gindi on Github.  I'm presenting a chart with a Limit Line and all is well.  When I add data to the chart, everything is working fine, yet the Limit Line appears twice.  I've tried reinitializing the Limit Line:

```
    var limitLine = ChartLimitLine()
    limitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: 
    self.averagePointsArray.average, label: "This weeks average")
    self.barChartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
    self.setChart()
```

I've also tried to use the methods:

barChartView.clear()
barChartView.clearValues()

Again, the data is chart is working fine.  Strange.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on iOS Charts is rather scarce as it was ported from an Android library (which is fully documented)

I came across this method that enables the removal of the Limit Line

```
barChartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(self.limitLine)
```

I remove it and add it back with the updated Limit Line value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

barChartView.rightAxis.removeAllLimitLines()

Before addLimitLine